# I am trying to insert an element at the end of an array in C++. Why is this approach not working?

Tags: c++, arrays, insert

```cpp
int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 100;
    int a[SIZE];
    int input, capacity = 0;
    cout << "ENter Values. Press Q to quit: " << endl;
    while (cin >> input)
    {
        if (capacity < SIZE)
        {
            a[capacity] = input;
            capacity++;
        }
    }

    int element;
    cout << "enter element to be inserted : " << endl;
    cin >> element;
    if (capacity < SIZE)
    {
        capacity++;
        a[capacity - 1] = element;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

When I am taking this approach, after I input the values, the program directly prints array (with an extra element). The program never gives a chance to enter the value of element. Why is this happening?

Comment: To me it looks as if the first loop fills the array, and there's no space left for the second loop. Did you try debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the following loop breaks,

```
while (cin >> input)
{
   ...
}
```

there is nothing to read from `cin` or `cin` is in an error state. Consequently, attempt to read from `cin` fails in the line

```
cin >> element;
```

That's why the program goes straight to the following line.

---

To resolve the problem,

1. Break out of the `while` loop after you have read `SIZE` number of elements.
2. Break out of the `while` loop by entering bad input. In this case, you'll have to clear the state of `cin`, discard a line of input, and then continue.

You can accomplish both by using.

```
while (capacity < SIZE && cin >> input)
{
    a[capacity] = input;
    capacity++;
}

// Did the while loop stop because of size or bad input?
if ( capacity < SIZE )
{
    // Bad input.
    // Clear the state of cin.
    // Read and discard the rest of the line.
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Now you can continue to read from `cin`.

**PS**

Add

```
#include <limits>
```

to be able to use `std::numeric_limits`.